# No matching signature for function STRING for argument types: INT64. Supported signature: STRING(TIMESTAMP, [STRING]) at [28:10]

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm new to Google BigQuery, so I've just started learning SQL.
I'm getting this error using STRING function (the Standard SQL is turned on).
I guess this function is not suitable for Standard SQL, how do I change it?

```
SELECT STRing(visitor_id) as id
No matching signature for function STRING for argument types: INT64. Supported signature: STRING(TIMESTAMP, [STRING]) at [28:10]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert and `int64` to a string, you can use `cast()`:

```
select cast(visitor_id as string)
```

As the error message suggests, the `string()` function is used on `timestamp`s to convert to a readable format.  It is basically shorthand for `format_timestamp()`, using a reasonable format.